# Magento 2.0 Front End Products Description Updating

Tags: magento, frontend, htmlbars

When I am updating the Products description on the Admin Panel for Magento 2.0, the space for description sometimes comes up without the HTML tool Bar. It also does not allow me to save the entered description. 
If I refresh the page, it works fine. I have seen this issue predominantly on Chrome and Internet Explorer browsers only.
I don’t work on Firefox a lot but I am yet to seen this error on Firefox.
Is this a known issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Will try Magento.stackexchange . Thank you!